# Can I use Magento Collections to a remote magento Database?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I connected to another magento database.

I use:

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('remote_write');
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('remote_read');
```

to connect and `$write->query("UPDATE table......etc");` to make my changes.

I want to select all products or a specific one from the remote database. To do that i have to write a crazy sql query that `left joins` all the EAV entities of the `catalog_product_entity` and then a

```
foreach($read->fetchAll($myquery) as $row) {
    /* do something */
}
```

to get all the product attributes.

Is there a way to get product attributes from the remote db using magento collections?

Comment: Really interesting problem you have their, afraid I don't have time to dig, but I would look at creating a custom module with Model Resource/Collection and extend `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` trying to connect to the remote db. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Magento's collections takes their data using resource models. Take a look at

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract::_getConnection($connectionName)
```

of resource model of your collection.